# How to use pagination in laravel api?

Tags: php, laravel, pagination

My problem: I need to use pagination in the simple api that I am trying to develop using laravel. I was using [Cursors](http://fractal.thephpleague.com/pagination/) to do it. But results are blank even if my model is returning result.

My code:

```
$newCursor = $groups->last()->id;
$cursor = new Cursor($cursor, $previousCursor, $newCursor, $groups->count());

//dd($cursor);

$groups =  new Collection(fractal($groups, new GroupRequestTransformer('filtered')));
$groups->setCursor($cursor);

$data = [
    'groups' => $groups,
    'cursor' => $cursor
 ];

$this->setResponseStatus(true, 200, trans('group.filtered'));
return $this->sendResponseData($data);
```

Note: `$groups` has values returned from model. And if I `dd($cursor);`, I get

```
Cursor {#403
  #current: "5"
  #prev: null
  #next: 13
  #count: 1
}
```

so this seems fine to. But the the actual response that I am sending as `$data` is blank.

```
"data": {
    "groups": {},
    "cursor": {}
  }
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Can't you use the native Laravel Pagination?

Comment: does it work in api? how do I send the 'next page' link?

Comment: Yes it works, it generates automatically a json response with all the data you need, just try to return your Eloquent Models from a controller:

`return User::paginate(10);`

Comment: I'm using transformers, so if I want to add a separate key for pagination there how do I get the pagination related values from the `$user` object?

Answer (score 1):

use fractal's paginator instance to format the paginated collection no need to use cursor below is the example on their site

```
use League\Fractal\Resource\Collection;
use League\Fractal\Pagination\IlluminatePaginatorAdapter;
use Acme\Model\Book;
use Acme\Transformer\BookTransformer;

$paginator = Book::paginate();
$books = $paginator->getCollection();

$resource = new Collection($books, new BookTransformer);
$resource->setPaginator(new IlluminatePaginatorAdapter($paginator));
```

see here http://fractal.thephpleague.com/pagination/

or use laravel-fractal a handy package which has support for all kind of pagination and everything.
https://github.com/spatie/laravel-fractal

Comment: "When we have large sets of data and running a `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM whatever` isn’t really an option" -- That's why I wanted to go with cursor.

Comment: i would suggest using spatie laravel-fractal i have dealt with more than 20 lakh rows and it doesn't create any problem pagination works correctly.